# Which data type holds Oracle sdo_Geometry data type in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net, geospatial

in Oracle Database, I have got a table which contains as a number, varchar etc variables. in addition, it has sdo_geometry object column. the task I have wanted, I would like to fetch this sdo_geometry data type and assign inside appropriate data type using c#. I will be happy if you solve this issue.

Thanks for now
Best Regards...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a .NET type you can map directly to that, but you can call `Get_WKT` to get the well known text.

```
SELECT ID, Name, myPolygon.Get_WKT() FROM YourSource
```

You can read that into a SqlGeometry object at run time if you need.

Comment: thank you @Fabulous I have solved this issue at last

Comment: I have got solution my own computer. I will share later to help other developers